# mongodb Java Driver performance issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am creating a restful service in java using mongodb as database.
The collection has a very large amount of data (almost 1.5 million)..

To return json using my service. I am using following code..

```
DBCollection tbl = db.getCollection();
DBCursor cur = tbl.find('tag',"")
BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
while(cur.hasNext())
    list.add(cur.next());
```

but this method is taking a very long time. Can you please suggest a way in which i can improve performance.

PS:I tried using

> cursor.toArray()

but it didn't increase performance time.

Comment: Is this program compile? because `db.getCollection()`, this is invalid method in `DB` class.

Comment: Do you have index on 'tag' field?

Comment: cursor.toArray() will not increase performance, it eager loads the database results into a in memory array, I am unsure where you got any information that it should help...

Comment: @ajduke this is just a sample code not the orginal i am using

Comment: @sody yes i have index on tag.. when i checked the time taken by each statement... tbl.find is taking about 500 ms where as the while loop is taking about 1 to 2 secs

Comment: @Sammaye yeah i thought cursor.toArray() will fetch data all at once from database which would be a improvement in performance.. but after testing it out i came to know that was not the case.. do u have any info regarding increasing the batch size on cursor and its effects on performance..

Comment: Can you run your query in the mongo shell with .explain(), and show us the results?